# Load Form with progress bar

Tags: c#

I want to load Form2. Form2 has a datagridview which will take time to load becouse it has a large amount of data.

I want to produce a progress bar while the form loads.
I came across with BackgroundWorker but im not sure how this works.

Comment: The first thing you need to know about progress bars is that **they are *not* automated**. You, the developer, need to tell it advance x percent at critical loading stages of the form. If you're getting the data from a database, then you need to get the amount of rows in the table, and then divide the current count in the loop with the total amount of rows.

Comment: Which then can apply to the PBar in a Timer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are excellent tutorials on the web for this problem:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo

And a youtube that explains it with cancellation even :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qQgctSi4iY

The key to remember is to use

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

and

```
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
```

As is explained in the demo as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at these links :)